# Google Script: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, urlfetch

This is my code:

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/#q=citrix&tbm=nws').getContentText();
var parsed = XmlService.parse(html);
```

It gives me this error:

> Error on line 1: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. (line 77, file "Code")

Not able to fix this, could you please help me out?
How can I bring this to well-formed one?

Comment: I think this problem is caused by your XML file, can you include your XML file here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355454/how-to-fix-error-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be)