# How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xml-validation

I put my code in the XML validation website and it gives me this error:

> Line 8: 4   The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

The line that is having an issue is the `<xsl:output method = "html" doctype-system = "about:legacy-compat"/>`, line.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- Fig. 15.21: sorting.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>

<!-- write XML declaration and DOCTYPE DTD information -->
*<xsl:output method = "html" doctype-system = "about:legacy-compat" />*

 <!-- match document root -->
 <xsl:template match="/"> -<html> <xsl:apply-templates/> </html> 
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### General case

> The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

This error indicates that your XML has markup following the root element. 
In order to be [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), XML [must have ***exactly one*** root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root), and there can be no further markup following the single root element.

**One root element example (GOOD)**

```
<r>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</r>
```

The most common sources for this error are:

1. **Including stray or extra close tags (BAD):**

   ```
   <r>
     <a/>
     <b/>
     <c/>
   </r>
   </r>  <!-- shouldn't be here -->
   ```
2. **Intentionally having multiple root elements (BAD):**

   ```
   <a/>
   <b/>  <!-- second root element shouldn't be here -->
   <c/>  <!-- third root element shouldn't be here -->
   ```
3. **Unintentionally having multiple root elements (BAD):**

   ```
   <r/>  <!-- shouldn't be self-closing -->
     <a/>
     <b/>
     <c/>
   </r>
   ```
4. **Parsing different XML than you think (BAD):**

   Log the XML immediately before providing to the parse that's
   failing in order to make sure that the XML that the parser is
   seeing is the same as the XML you think it's seeing.  Common
   errors here include:

   - The filename of the XML document being passed to the 
     parser differs from what you believe it is.
   - The buffer of the XML being dirty.  Make sure it's been
     cleared prior to adding your XML.
   - An earlier program from a prior stage in your pipeline
     changing the XML prior to the parsing that's yielding
     this error message.

---

### Your particular problem

In your particular case, your XML appears to have multiple root elements because the `xsl:stylesheet` element is closed prematurely (case **#3** above).

Change

```
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
```

to

```
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

to fix your immediate problem, and add a closing tag,

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if one does not already exist in your real document.

Comment: Copy that, KJH, I had the closing tag down on about line 18. Thank you for your time and timely response.

Comment: HA, I jinxed my self. And I will accept the above answer. Question; I ran the entire thing through the XML Validation site, I received no errors. I loaded it onto my schools webserver to render the page in Chrome so I could turn it in for my homework this week. Chome is giving me an error on line 8 also;  
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 8 at column 3: Extra content at the end of the document. Is the extra content at the end of the document referring to that particular line or then end of the entire document?

Comment: @Mereinid: Please read [**Well-formed vs Valid XML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) and understand that neither being well-formed nor valid implies correctness of your XSLT.  See also [**Running XSLT in a Web Browser**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942399/290085).  Beyond this answer and those two answers, you'll have to post another question if you're still having problems.  Comments aren't meant for new questions -- just clarifications.  Thank you.

Comment: Very detailed use-cases, thanks @kjhughes. I may add my 2 cents, sometimes you may have some well formed _looking_ XML giving you the same error as OP's upon parsing. One possible reason is the XML might contain invisible characters such as but not limited to `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` (U+200B) or `ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK SPACE` (U+FEFF). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619264/html-how-to-remove-zero-width-no-break-space) gives a trick to spot and remove them.

Comment: I saw this error when an opening html tag got copy/pasta'ed (deleted). The xml parser was throwing an error on the line of the opening body tag.

Answer (score -1):

this also may show up because of wrong spaces in this file

Comment: An example of this error arising due to "wrong spaces in this file" would make your answer immensely more useful.  As it stands, it's not helpful.