# How to make a GoogleApp Script that will pull values from website using weblinks and xpaths?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use about 300 importxml functions, but they can be slow. I am trying to create an AppScript in Google Sheets that will go through a table, row by row, a pull the value from the website. Column1 is the link, column2 is the xpath, column3 is the value from the website I need (output).

Here is two rows of the table as an example.

| Weblink | Xpath |
| --- | --- |
| https://cbcmustangs.com/sports/mbkb/2023-24/schedule | /html/body/main/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2] |
| https://columbiacougars.com/sports/mens-basketball/schedule/2023-24 | /html/body/form/main/article/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[2] |

```
function customImportXML() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Replace 'YourSheetName' with your sheet's name

  // Get the data range in the sheet
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  
  // Iterate through each row in the sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) { // Start from row 2 (assuming row 1 contains headers)
    var url = values[i][0]; // URL in column 1
    var xpath = values[i][1]; // XPath in column 2
    
    if (url && xpath) {
      try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        var content = response.getContentText();

        // Parse the content as XML
        var document = XmlService.parse(content);
        var root = document.getRootElement();
        
        // Use XPath to find the value
        var result = XmlService.get(xpath, root).getText();
        
        // Update the value in column 3
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue(result);
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle errors (e.g., invalid URL, XPath not found)
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue('Error: ' + e.toString());
      }
    } else {
      // If either URL or XPath is missing, indicate it in column 3
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue('Missing URL or XPath');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355454/how-to-fix-error-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be)

Comment: I read through. I am not really sure how to make it "well-informed".

Comment: if the website is not well formed and it's also not your website then there's not much you can do about it and Googles XML Service will probably not be useful for you.